Change the subnet mask using nmcli
Directly doing this is pretty simple;
sudo ip addr del 10.0.5.8/16 dev eth4 && sudo ip addr add 10.0.5.8/24 dev eth4

What's the equivalent notation when using nmcli? Just doing this is not enough to also change it in the currently active session;
CONNGUID=$(sudo nmcli con | grep eth4 | grep -Po '[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}')
sudo nmcli con modify $CONNGUID ipv4.addresses 10.0.5.8/24 && sudo systemctl restart networking

Verifying using ip addr show dev eth4 | grep '10.0.5.8/16' still shows me that the configuration change doesn't stick.
